# Number of functions from $\mathbb{Z}_m$ to $\mathbb{Z}_n$.

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

I'm just wondering if there's a generalised way of computing the number of functions from $\mathbb{Z}_m$ to $\mathbb{Z}_n$, and additionally the number of one-to-one and onto functions between $\mathbb{Z}_m$ and $\mathbb{Z}_n$.

Comment: The cardinality of the set of functions from a set $\ D\ $ to a set $\ C\ $ is $\ |C|^{|D|}\ $, where $\ |S|\  $ is the cardinality of the set $\ S\ $.  The number of functions from $\ \mathbb{Z}_m\ $ to $\ \mathbb{Z}_n\ $ is therefore $\ n^m\ $.

Comment: Thanks. How do you find the number of one-to-one and onto functions between the two though?

Comment: If there is no question about homomorphism of group structures then why have you written $\Bbb{Z}_n$ instead of simply $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$?

Comment: I mean.. Aren't they equivalent in this context? This was the way that the question was stated in my course material.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We will count functions $f:[m]\to [n],$ of the general, injective, and surjective kind. You did not mention anything about preserving group or ring structures, so we will not pay attention to that.

1. The number of general functions is $$\underbrace{n\cdot n\cdots n}_{m \text{ copies of } n}=n^m.$$
2. Assuming $n\ge m,$ he number of injective functions is $$n(n-1)\cdots (n-m+1)=\frac{n!}{(n-m)!}.$$ If $n<m,$ then there are no injective functions.
3. We can find the number of surjective functions using the [symmetric principle of inclusion-exclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle#A_special_case). The idea is to let $F_i$ be the number of functions $g:[m]\to[n]$ where $i$ is missed in the range (others might be missed too). Using the first formula, we get $$n^m - \left|\bigcup_{i=1}^{n}F_i\right|=\sum_{i=0}^{n}{(-1)^i\binom{n}{i}(n-i)^m}.$$ You should be able to figure out the details of that computation if you study the principle of inclusion-exclusion. This formula gives $0$ if $n>m,$ as it should since there are no surjections in that case.

This is a part of a larger set of problems called the [Twelvefold Way](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twelvefold_way), which are covered fairly formally in Richard Stanley's [Enumerative Combinatorics](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1107602629).

Comment: Thank you so much! This is precisely what I'm looking for!